# Could not establish an API connection in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, credentials

For retrieving monitoring metrics from my project, I used below Python code:

```py
from google.cloud import monitoring_v3
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient import discovery

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
   r'D:\GCP\credentials\blahblah-04e8fd0245b8.json')

service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()

project_name = f"projects/{blahblah-300807}"

resource_descriptors = client.list_monitored_resource_descriptors(
    name=project_name)

for descriptor in resource_descriptors:
    print(descriptor.type)
```

I did everything well. I gave the file path for credentials information correctly, but I received this error message:

```sh
raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: \
Could not automatically determine credentials. \
Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create \
credentials and re-run the application. \
For more information, please see \
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

I even checked that link and tried the alternative method, but still, it didn't work. How can I rectify this? Am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the credential when you create the client

```
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient()
```

You can change it like this

```
client = monitoring_v3.MetricServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
```

---

Personally, I prefer to not explicitly provide the credential in the code, and I prefer to use the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` for this.

Create an environment variable in your OS with the name `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` and the value that point to the service account key file `D:\GCP\credentials\blahblah-04e8fd0245b8.json`.

But, if it's on your own computer, you can even don't use service account key file (which is not really secure, I explain why in [this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/the-2-limits-of-iam-service-on-google-cloud-7db213277d9c)), you can use your own credential. For this, simply create an application default credential (ADC) like this `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: Thank you. It worked by passing the credentials as an argument as you said. I created the environmental variable with passing the json file as value, but that didn't work

Comment: Because you are on Windows OS, and because it's Windows OS, have you restarted your computer after having set the environment variable?